# Should we error check every call in C?

Tags: c, error-handling

When we write C programs we make calls to malloc or printf. But do we need to check every call? What guidelines do you use?

e.g.

```
char error_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];
if (fclose(file) == EOF) {
    sprintf(error_msg, "Error closing %s\n", filename);
    perror(error_msg);
}
```

Comment: I don't check for `printf`, if that fails, then it's really something wrong with your computer. `fprintf` I check but only if the writing operation is essential, if it''s a log, I don't check it. `malloc` & co, I always check for them, even if sometimes this is annoying.

Comment: You cannot say that in general. As a thumb of rule you should check for everything that can go wrong and – if it is the case – when you have a strategy to handle that. For example checking `malloc()`  on hosted systems typically leads to program termination, because your program will not behave as intended, if it does not have enough memory.

Comment: Even in the case of a malloc failure you can at least set up beforehand so that you can terminate gracefully.

Comment: The most common reason for `malloc()` to fail in my experience is not that you have run out of heap space but that the memory size requested is a stupid number - often because some `int` has been overwritten by a pointer value or it is uninitialised.  So putting a check there at least stops the rot, although there is not much you can do except report the issue and exit.

Comment: regarding the code block that calls `fclose()`.  The following call to `sprintf()` will change the value in `errno`, so the call to `perror()` should be before the call to `sprintf()`

Comment: the simplest way to look at it is:  WHEN the application crashes, do you/the user want to know why it failed, so you can remedy the problem and run the application again or do you want to pretend that failures never happen and thereby have the users toss the application in the trash;  It is up to you?

Comment: @user3629249 That is code from a program of mine, if it changes errno, what is a different way I can create an error message, since perror doesn't allow string formatting?

Comment: save the value in `errno`, then call `fprintf( stderr, "format string", ... );`  where the format string ends with `%s\n` and the last parameter is `strerror( savedValueOfErrno )`  Of course this means the statement: `#include <errno.h>` must be in your program.

Comment: @user3629249 Sweet, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: "Do whatever you want", there is no written rule, BUT the right question is "What do users want in case of failure".

Let me explain, if you are a student writing a test program for example, no absolute need to check for errors: it may be a waste of time.

Now, if your code may be distributed or used by other people, that quite different: put yourself in the shoes of future users. Which message do you prefer when something goes wrong with an application:

```
Core was generated by `./cut --output-d=: -b1,1234567890- /dev/fd/63'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

or

```
MySuperApp failed to start MySuperModule because there is not enough space on the disk.
Try to free space on disk, then relaunch the app. 
If this error persists contact us at support@mysuperapp.com
```

As it has already been addressed in the comment, you have to consider two types of error:

- A **fatal error** is one that kills your program (app / server / site / whatever it is). It renders it unusable, either by crashing or by putting it in some state whereby it can't do it's usable work. e.g. memory allocation, disk space ...
- **Non-fatal error** is one where something messes up, but the program can continue to do what it's supposed to do. e.g. file not found, serve other users not requesting the thing that called the error.

Source : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-error-and-a-fatal-error

Answer (score 0):

Just do error checking if your program behaviour has to behave differently in case an error is detected.  Let me illustrate this with an example:  Assume you have used a temporary file in your program and you use the `unlink(2)` system call to erase that temporary file at the end of the program.  Have you to check if the file has been successfully erased?  Let's analyse the problem with some common sense:  if you check for errors, are you going to be able (inside the program) of doing some alternate thing to cope with this?  This is uncommon (if you created the file, it's rare that you will not be able to erase it, but something can happen in the time between --- for example a change in directory permissions that forbids you to write on the directory anymore)  But what can you do in that case?  Is it possible to use a different approach to erase temporary file in that case. Probably not... so checking (in that case) a possible error from the `unlink(2)` system call will be almost useless.

Of course, this doesn't apply always, you have to use common sense while programming.  Errors about writing to files should be always considered, as they belong to access permissions or mostly to full filesystems (In that case, even trying to generate a log message can be useles, as you have filled your disk --- or not, that depends)  Do you know always the precise environment details to obviate if a full filesystem error can be ignored.  Suppose you have to connect to a server in your program.  Should the `connect(2)` system call failure be acted upon?  probably most of the times, at least a message to the user with the protocol error (or the cause of the failure) must be given to the user.... assuming everything goes ok can save you time in a prototype, but you have to cope with what can happen, in production programs.

Answer (score 0):

When i want to use return value of function than suggested to check return value before using it
For example pointer return address that can be null also.so suggested to keep null check before using it.